# SDL_AddTimer in which way it is used to avoid multithreading problems

Tags: multithreading, sdl, sdl-2

[Wiki Link for SDL_AddTimer](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_AddTimer)

The wiki document for SDL_AddTimer claims that

**"Note that it is possible to avoid the multithreading problems with SDL timers by giving to userevent.data1 the address of a function you want to be executed and to userevent.data2 its params, and then deal with it in the event loop."**

How it is used to avoid multithreading problem?. 
Can someone explain what is it i am unable to understand the statement ?

Answer (score 1):

The first example assumes the working function, i.e. the function you want to execute ( my_function() ), resides in the my_callbackfunc() function.

SDL_AddTimer() specifies: Use this function to set up a callback function to be run on a *separate thread* after the specified number of milliseconds has elapsed.

This will introduce concurrency problems with my_function().

The solution (second example), assumes the event polling thread is the same thread that added the timer, and calls the function in that thread.

Answer (score 0):

I've read that SDL documentation as well, and it makes a **really** bad suggestion for its "workaround". Specifically, it recommends casting a function address to a void pointer. This is not portable! Do not do it and please read

https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/pointers-to-members#cant-cvt-fnptr-to-voidptr

If you feel that you must do this (or something like it) then I'd suggest wrapping the function pointer inside a struct/class.

```
struct Wrapper
{
 void (*f)(void*);
 Wrapper(void (*F)(void*)) { f = F; }
};
```

Create the wrapper when you want to push the custom event

```
SDL_Event event;
event.user.data1 = (void*) new Wrapper(your_function);
event.user.data2 = your_function_arg;
SDL_PushEvent(&user);
```

Then in your main loop, do the call, delete the wrapper

```
SDL_WaitEvent(&event);
if (event.type == SDL_USEREVENT)
{
 Wrapper *p = ((Wrapper*) event.user.data1)
 p->f(event.user.data2);
 delete p;
}
```